# Service vs component

Tags: angular

I have listed out the menu, which has to be used in different module and as well as components. like home screen, report screen etc.

Initially i have parsed the menu and save in the common class which has the main template, all my modules components are listed here. so i passed my parsed menu as a input in all the listed components.

now i thought, instead of passing input to the components, i have created a menu service which has menu parsing, selected menu, default menu are saved here. Then i have injected the menu service to the components which need menu list.

is i am doing right or i need to stick on the old way.

suggestion please.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

I would create a module with a component that contains the menu.
And all other pages are behind the routingmodule, so every page contains the module.
Just disable the menu for pages you don't need.